# Export Core Data with strings and images to excel

Tags: ios, excel, core-data

I am using Core Data in an iPhone app in which there are strings and images and I want to be able to export it to an excel file.

A line of the table would look like this :
project;category;description;recommendation;**image**

I have tried to use CHCSVParser (https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) and XMLWriter (https://github.com/skjolber/xswi/tree/master/xswi) but it is impossible to put the images in the table with them...

So if anyone has a solution for me it would be great ! Thanks

Comment: Do you literally want the image data, the pixels, inline in the exported file? I can't picture what that would even look like. Can you give us an example of the image format that Excel wants, or link to documentation? Or is it just that you want the image URL/filename inline?

Comment: yes I'd like the image data in the exported file, which means in the box next to the one with "recommendation" you would have the image itself. A JPEG image format is accepted by Excel